# Visual Studio Unexpectedly Adding Feature on Load

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, visual-studio-2013

I have a SharePoint 2010 solution in Visual Studio 2013. Every time I close and reopen Visual Studio, a new feature is added to the solution with one list inside it. The list was removed from another feature that it should be in. It is always the same list. As soon as I open the solution this pops up in the Output window before I do anything...

> `A new feature Feature2 has been added to the project Solution`
>   `C:\Code\Solution\Package\Package.package (0,0): Added Feature2 to Package`

What is causing this?

I have tried the following:

1. Recreated the solution and copied all files over - No change
2. Checked the package and project manifest. - Everything looks okay.
3. Loaded the project every different way, including unload and reload command. - No change
4. Recreated the list it likes to isolate into its own feature - No change
5. Recreated the feature the list should be in but it keeps moving to this new feature - No change
6. Added a new list and put it after the problem list in the feature - **VS then created 3 new features! It took 3 lists out of my feature and put one in each of its own features. I guess I made it angry.**

Comment: From [Xiaoying's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3630491/xiaoying) [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25875621/1454048), as she has too-low rep to comment: "Do your lists have the same Type ID? If the lists in the same feature have the same Type ID, the tooling will move the lists into a newly created feature, because the Type must be unique within a feature. You can check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms462947(v=office.15).aspx for more information."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the lists in the same feature have the same Type ID, the tooling will move the lists into a newly created feature, because the Type must be unique within a feature. You can check the documentation on the [`ListTemplate` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms462947.aspx) for more information.

Comment: This post is better suited as a comment to the original question (having too-low reputation to post comments is also not an excuse to post comments as answers).

Comment: This is the answer. I guess this means I cannot have 2 document libraries in the same feature.

Comment: Perhaps @Xiaoying can reword her response to more of an "answer" format and we can remove the downvote?

Comment: Thank you guys. I provided a lot of answers in the past, but still new to this site (yeah, shame on me). Appreciate all of your comments on how to use StackOverflow.

Answer (score 5):

It is because features cannot contain list templates that have identical values for `Type`. This is explained here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms462947.aspx

> Type
>
> Optional Integer.
>
> Provides a unique identifier for the template. This identifier must be unique within the feature, but need not be unique across all feature definitions or site definitions. For a list of the default list template types, see SPListTemplateType.

You will probably find that your Elements.xml file for your list templates contains the same value for Type.

To fix this, you will need to edit the Elements.xml files of the list template and the list instance.

1. Change the Type of the ListTemplate xml element to a unique integer.
2. Change the TemplateType of the ListInstance xml element to the same integer

I have started to choose numbers over 1000 to avoid conflicts (Although 1100, 1200, 1220 and 1221 are system types)

Comment: Great first half of the answer. Though the second half, speaking of changing the Type IDs, is not always a good idea. Changing the Type IDs results in SharePoint not recognizing the modified one as the type it originally was. I had this problem with two calendars in the same feature. I changed the IDs and hat some settings and features missing in the ribbon after I deployed the feature and tried to use the calendars.