# Visual Studio makes 1 feature per list

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013

I'm running into an odd problem with Visual Studio 2013 (Update 3) and SharePoint 2013.  I created a Sandboxed solution for SharePoint 2013.  I then right-clicked on the solution 7 times and selected to add a new List each time.  VS created a new feature for each list.  I deleted all but the first feature and added each list to that feature, so the end result was 1 feature with 7 list definitions and 7 list instances.

Builds and deploys just fine.

I then closed the solution and opened it again.  VS created 6 new features and put 1 list definition and list instance in each feature.  Is there a way for me to put all of my list definitions and instances into a single feature?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Unexpectedly Adding Feature on Load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25857722/visual-studio-unexpectedly-adding-feature-on-load)

Answer (score 4):

I think I found a solution. What I needed to do was to change the template type from the default of 100 to something else. I changed mine to 10000 for the first list definition and then changed the template type to 10001 for the second list definition. The second list definition was automatically added to the same feature as the first. Hope this helps.

Comment: Did you have the _exact_ same problem as the OP? In particular, the "I then closed the solution and opened it again. VS created 6 new features"?

Comment: Yes, the exact same issue.  Here's the explanation: "Type
Optional Integer. Provides a unique identifier for the template. This identifier must be unique within the feature".  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms462947%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: This was actually answered in this question so I guess this is a duplicate.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25857722/visual-studio-unexpectedly-adding-feature-on-load